# Как отрисовывать окружность при движении мыши? (Paper.js)

Tags: javascript

Использую Paper.js

Задача:

Если на canvas'e нажать и удерживать ЛКМ, а потом начать отводить курсор - то за курсором должна строиться окружность (где центр окружности - координаты первого клика, а радиус - расстояние от центра до текущего положения курсора).

Как только пользователь отпустит ЛКМ - окружность перестаёт изменять размер, а в том месте, где потльзователь отпустил мышь создаётся точка (соответственно она лежит на окружности и пренадлежит ей).

Проблема заключается в отрисовки окружности, в тот момент когда пользователь удерживает ЛКМ и меняет положение курсора.

Comment: Есть рабочий пример http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/nXmTC/ смотрите сами. Только там по горизонтали положение мыши считается а по вертикали нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если функционалом paper.js, то вот так у меня работает.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas-0">
var mycircle;
var myvector;
tool.minDistance = 1;
tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    mycircle = new Shape.Circle(event.point,0);
    mycircle.strokeColor = 'black';
}

tool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
 myvector=event.point-mycircle.position;
    mycircle.radius=myvector.length;
}
tool.onMouseUp = function(event) {
 mycircle = new Shape.Circle(event.point,1);
 mycircle.strokeColor = 'black';
}
</script>
<canvas id="canvas-0" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #999;"></canvas>
```

===
Добавил создание точки при отпускании кнопки мыши.